# How can std::lock_guard be faster than std::mutex::lock()?

Tags: c++, mutex

I was arguing with a colleague, about lock_guard, and he proposed that lock_guard is problably slower than mutex::lock() / mutex::unlock() due to the cost of instantiate and unistantiate the class lock_guard.

Then I created this simple test and, surprisely, the version with lock_guard is almost two times faster than the version with mutex::lock() / mutex::unlock()

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

std::mutex m;
int g = 0;

void func1()
{
    m.lock();
    g++;
    m.unlock();
}

void func2()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    g++;
}

int main()
{
    auto t = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        func1();
    }

    std::cout << "Take: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - t).count() << " ms" << std::endl;

    t = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        func2();
    }

    std::cout << "Take: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - t).count() << " ms" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The results on my machine:

```sh
Take: 41 ms
Take: 22 ms
```

Can someone clarify why and how this can be?

Comment: and how many times did you take your measurements?

Comment: Please post your compiler flags... Benchmarking will depend on optimization level...

Comment: Pro Tip: When doing measurements like this, swap the order to make sure it isn't just cold data/instructions causing the issue: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81f75a1ab52cb1cc

Comment: It seens that the order was affecting the results. When I duplicate the code, the result was this:
Take: 42 ms (func1)
Take: 23 ms (func2)
Take: 12 ms (func1)
Take: 19 ms (func2)

Comment: Another thing that's helpful when doing measurements like this: put the whole thing in a larger loop, so that you run the whole measurement set, say, 20 times each run. Usually the later measurements will be the ones that are actually meaningful, because by then the cache has settled into whatever behavior it's likely to have in the long term.

Comment: You can use Quick Bench for these types of test : http://quick-bench.com/b31hkSLtNDeE5DtmdEXLjTY8FCw If you aren't profiling real code, it gives you a good general idea.

Comment: Even if `std::lock_guard` was a bit slower, unless you can prove that it matters in terms of performance, that speed gain will not invalidate the other benefits of using `std::lock_guard` (mainly RAII). If `g++` is anything that can throw or anything that might change into something potentially more complicated in the future you almost *have* to use some sort of object to own the lock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The release build produces the same result for both versions.

The `DEBUG` build shows ~33% longer time for `func2`; the difference I see in the disassembly that `func2` uses `__security_cookie` and invokes `@_RTC_CheckStackVars@8`.

Are you timing DEBUG?

EDIT:
Additionally, while looking at `RELEASE` disassembly, I noticed that `mutex` methods were saved in two registries:

```
010F104E  mov         edi,dword ptr [__imp___Mtx_lock (010F3060h)]  
010F1054  xor         esi,esi  
010F1056  mov         ebx,dword ptr [__imp___Mtx_unlock (010F3054h)]
```

and called the same way from both `func1` and `func2`:

```
010F1067  call        edi  
....
010F107F  call        ebx
```